# Implementing Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech recognition for several files

Tags: java, azure-cognitive-services

I have gotten the coding example from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-recognize-speech-java#continuous-speech-recognition-from-a-file) to work.

I can run a .wav file through and get the transcript, however in the example the program never ends until I hit a key:

```
System.out.println("Press any key to stop");
new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
```

That seems to artificially pause everything while the service is being queried.
If I remove those that line, the program jumps through to fast and concludes without waiting for the service to respond.

**Question**: How do I resume/continue the program with the full transcription without needing to hit a key?

I would like to run this for multiple .wav files transcribing each one after the other. But so far it runs the first one then waits.

I have been scouring the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechrecognizer?view=azure-dotnet) and I have tried multiple things including using `recognizer.close();` which I would expect to end the `SpeechRecognizer` but which seems to do nothing.

Or using `result = recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync().get();` which does not transcribe the full file.

Does anyone know of an example of this running multiple files or how to implement that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that will read and return the list of files in your directory:

```
private static String[] GetFiles(String directory)
{
    String[] files = (new File(directory)).list(File::isFile);
    return files;
}
```

Then loop through them to process them, and then transcribe them.

```
String[] files = GetFiles(args[0]);
for (String file : files)
{
    //Your code goes here.
    System.out.printf("File %1$s processed" + "\r\n",file);//print out which file has been successfully processed.
}
```

You could also try using the [Batch Transcription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription) feature!

> Batch transcription is ideal if you have large amounts of audio in
>   storage.